# Controlling width of two floating divs displayed in reverse order no matter the width of content in divs

Tags: html, css, width, floating

I would like to have two floating divs on a page with their combined width filling the entire width of a browser window. I want one div to have a fixed width of 15em and be displayed on the left. I'll call this the sidebar div. I want the other div to use the rest of the available width, dynamically, and be displayed on the right. I'll call this the main content div.

I want the width of the main content div to fill all of the available width that is not used by the sidebar div and I want this to happen even if none of the content in the main content div needs all of the available width.

To further complicate things, I want the main content div to be coded before the sidebar div but I want the sidebar div to display on the left before the main content div on the right. This complication is what makes my question different than other similar questions I have found from other users here.

I have everything functioning the way I want except on pages where there is no content needing the full available width of the main content div. For example, if I have a line of text in a p that wraps to the next line because it is longer than the available width, everything functions as desired. When the line of text in a p is not long enough to utilize the full amount of width available for the main content div, the main content div is only as wide as its content requires and it hangs out on the right of the page leaving a big empty space between the sidebar and main content divs.

```css
.right-main-content {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 16em;
  padding: 0;
  background: red
}

.left-sidebar {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 15em;
  margin-right: -15.5em;
  background: green
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="right-main-content">
    <p>
      This is the right main content div.
    </p>
    <p>
  </div>
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    <p>this is the left sidebar div</p>
    <p>with a fixed width of 15em</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a calculation-driven `width` that is `100%` of the parent, minus the `15em` width of the left sidebar. This can be achieved by using **[calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)**:

```css
.right-main-content {
  float: right;
  width: calc(100% - 15em);
  background: red;
}

.left-sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 15em;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="right-main-content">
    <p>
      This is the right main content div.
    </p>
    <p>
  </div>
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    <p>this is the left sidebar div</p>
    <p>with a fixed width of 15em</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

This way, all you need to specify are the two `width` and `float` properties.

Also note that you don't need `text-align: left`, as it is left-aligned by default.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `calc` in css and Viewport Sized Typography to set the width on your right div.

as per your example try this:

```
.left-sidebar {
  width:15em;
  float:left;
}

.right-main-content {
  width:calc(100vw - 16em);
  float:right;
}
```

Here is an example I've created.
 https://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/eEYoeX

Answer (score 0):

You could try floating `div.left-sidebar` only and make the margin-right value of `div.right-main-content` same as `div.left-sidebar` width as follows:

```
.right-main-content {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 15em;
  padding: 0;
  background: red;
  width:100%;
}

.left-sidebar {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 15em;
  background: green
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/w0azuoLq/